# A subview is displayed in different places on two views with the same frame and superview

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiscrollview, uilabel

I am trying to add a subview to a certain view (Bad View) and it always appears a little bit to the right of where I want it to be (x values on screen are different).

However, I have noticed that when I add this subview to a different view (Good View) it is placed in the correct position.

Bad View and Good View are children of the same view and have the same frame (Good View is a zoomable view in a scroll view while Bad View is an overlay view that does not zoom).

I run the following code:

```
view.frame = [[self tiledScrollView] tileContainerView].frame;

if ([[[self tiledScrollView] tileContainerView] superview] == [view superview])
{
    NSLog(@"SAME SUPERVIEWS");
}

[[self tiledScrollView] tileContainerView].frame = view.frame;

NSLog(@"FRAME FOR VIEW THAT DISPLAYS INCORRECTLY: %f, %f, %f, %f, \n FRAME FOR VIEW THAT DISPLAYS CORRECTLY: %f, %f, %f, %f", view.frame.origin.x, view.frame.origin.y, view.frame.size.width, view.frame.size.height, [[self tiledScrollView] tileContainerView].frame.origin.x, [[self tiledScrollView] tileContainerView].frame.origin.y, [[self tiledScrollView] tileContainerView].frame.size.width, [[self tiledScrollView] tileContainerView].frame.size.height);
```

And immediately after that I add the subview to either [[self tiledScrollView] tileContainerView] (Good View) or to view (Bad View).

In Good View the label appears where I want it to. In Bad View the label appears a little bit to the right.

The output from the above code is:

SAME SUPERVIEWS

FRAME FOR VIEW THAT DISPLAYS INCORRECTLY: 0.000275, 0.000000, 983.999451, 648.282349, 
 FRAME FOR VIEW THAT DISPLAYS CORRECTLY: 0.000293, -0.000003, 983.999390, 648.282349

So they actually don't have exactly the same frames (even though I set them equal right before) but they are extremely close and the only place a difference from rounding could occur is in the origin.y values, but the difference when the application runs is in the origin.x values.

I've wasted so much time trying to figure this out so help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A view's `frame` is its bounding rectangle in the coordinate system of its superview. One thing that *could* be happening is that Bad View and Good View differ in their own coordinate systems. That would easily explain why your subview ends up in different locations on the screen. An easy way to check would be to log the `bounds` for each view instead of the `frame`. `bounds` gives you the view's bounding rectangle in its own coordinate system -- if they're not the same, you've found the cause of your problem.

Comment: Aha! Bounds is indeed different. Thank you this is very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Try instead of

```
[[self tiledScrollView] tileContainerView].frame = view.frame;
```

this

```
[[self tiledScrollView] tileContainerView].frame.origin.x    = view.frame.origin.x;
[[self tiledScrollView] tileContainerView].frame.origin.y    = view.frame.origin.y;
[[self tiledScrollView] tileContainerView].frame.size.width  = view.frame.size.width;
[[self tiledScrollView] tileContainerView].frame.size.height = view.frame.size.height;
```

or reverse as I see that from your output, the output shows that view.frame is the INCORRECT one:

```
view.frame.origin.x    = [[self tiledScrollView] tileContainerView].frame.origin.x;
view.frame.origin.y    = [[self tiledScrollView] tileContainerView].frame.origin.y;
view.frame.size.width  = [[self tiledScrollView] tileContainerView].frame.size.width;
view.frame.size.height = [[self tiledScrollView] tileContainerView].frame.size.height;
```